# C# list grouping on multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have an OrderBlock object that contain a list of Orders. This list is bound to my datagrid.

The list often contain multiple orders for the same stock, say Microsoft. Some of the orders might be buy others might be sell orders.

I want to group my list based on the Order.Id and Order.Side but I am unsure how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var grouped = list.GroupBy(x => new {x.Id, x.Side});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use something like this:

```
var results = 
    from o in OrderBlock
    group o by new { o.Id, o.Side };
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var results = OrderBlock.GroupBy(o => new { o.Id, o.Side });
```